# Doctrine 2/DB design question: Users, Companies, UsersCompanies Reference Table, and where to include field for current company?

Tags: php, database, database-design, orm, doctrine

I'm using Doctrine 2 for my ORM and for my app I have Users, who can have a many to many relationship with Companies, but a user can only have one active/current company.  My question is where to include the field marking the user's current firm.  My thoughts are that there are two options:
1) Adding an isCurrent field to the UsersCompanies reference table.  However, if I want to get a user's current company, I would have to cycle through the a user's UsersCompanies references and check the is_current field for each reference.
2) Putting a current_users_companies_id in the user's table, so that it can be easily accessed.

As always, I appreciate your time and input.

Answer (score 2):

Well, since the user can have only one current company, it would lead me to think it's a specific one-to-many relationship. Thus the best (and the simplest :) ) way to do it would be to just have the current_company_id property in your user object.

Comment: appreciate your input.  I edited my post actually, and just to clarify, the usersCompanies table also holds other information like job title, office location, etc, which is specific to the relationship between the user and the company.  Therefore, it is a reference table and not a join table.  Would this change your answer?  In this case, it would be difficult to retrieve a company's current employees, as I would have to cycle through the references to check if the user's current firm matches.  Is there a more efficient way of handling this?

Comment: Well, if you were to use a current_company_id in the user, you could make it a relation in Doctrine 2. Then, you could simply create the opposite end of the relation on your company entity - This would allow you to simply get this field from the company to find all the current employees.

Comment: I would also need a current_user_company_reference_id in order to quickly access the user's current UserCompanyReference entity, as that holds other info related to the relationship, so would it be denormalized design if I had both a current_company_id and a current_user_company_reference_id?  Thx again, really appreciate your input.

Comment: You could alternatively use a getter in your entity, which loops the user company references to determine the current company's information. If it later seems you would get a performance boost from using an additional field, it should be relatively straightforward to add - simply add the new property, and change the getter so it uses the property instead of looping.